# Как измерить ресурсоёмкость html приложения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, тестирование

Есть html приложение (html,css, javascript). Есть, ли способ как тестировать ресурсы компютера(оперативная память, процесор, видеоускоритель) при выполнении приложения ?

Так как приложение динамическое , там много графики и много анимации, то интересует именно вариант в реальном времени посмотреть как изменяеться нагрузка на оборудование при запуске тех или иных функций.

Интерсуют любые варианты (модули nod.js, плагины на браузер итд)

Comment: ну как минимум `F12 - Timeline` штатное средство для хрома и иже с ним

Comment: @ SLy_huh, а там можно смотреть в динамике ? У меня оно показывает, только нугрузку при загрузке приложения ...

Comment: Ну у меня он автозавершает запись на 4х секундах при загрузке страниц, видимо стандартная отбивка. А запись в любой момент времени включается на `ctrl + e`

Comment: Может, есть что-то наподобе диспетчера задач как для винды ток для html приложений ? Интересует именно просмотр в реальном времени а не запись...

Comment: Именно браузерных решений я не знаю, сам отлаживаю по консоли/диспетчеру задач виндовскому(реалтайм). Если надо чекнуть нагрузку гпу, просто скачай утилитку для мониторинга. По моему, куда проще, чем искать нечто специфичное